# Inlcude fftw3.h with cmake in a linux environment

Tags: c++, cmake, fftw

I want to use fftw library.

In my cpp file I included as `#include <fftw3.h>`

I downloaded the library and I saved it in ./fftw
Then I typed:

```
cd fftw
./configure
make
make install
cd ..
```

In my project I am already using OpenCV, so my CMakeLists.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8) # CMake version check
project( main ) 
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_executable( main main.cpp )
# set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
target_link_libraries( main ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
target_link_libraries( main ./fftw)
```

Finally I execute `cmake CMakeLists.txt` but when I try to `make` my executable, it complains that fftw3.h: No such file or directory.

How could I make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is this `fftw.h` header file located in relation to `main.cpp` (where I assume you attempt to include it)? And *how* do you attempt to include the header file? Please try to create a [mre] to show us (together with a full and complete copy-paste of the error output).

Comment: The only place I found this fftw.h is in ./fftw/api/fftw3.h (being main.cpp in . )

Comment: And about the minimal reproducible example, I just get the error of No such file or directory. To download the library is here: http://www.fftw.org/download.html, and main.cpp does not need anything else but an #include <fftw3.h>, then I just followed what I mentioned in the post.

Comment: `#include <fftw.h>` will make the preprocessor to look for `fftw.h` in the compilers system directories. If the header file isn't in a system directory then you need to add it to the path to be search with the `-I` (upper-case i) flag for the compiler. Which happens with e.g. the CMake `include_directories` command.

Comment: Also, when adding libraries to link with in CMake, you need to list the actual library itself and not a project root directory.

Comment: By the way, why haven't you tried to install fftw from whatever package repository available on your system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `./configure --prefix /where/you/want/to/install` to set the directory you want the library to be installed in then make sure that you run `make install` inside `./fftw` directory.

You may need to use `sudo make install` depending on the path and permissions.

Change your CMakeLists.txt to include the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8) # CMake version check
project( main ) 
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_executable( main main.cpp )
# set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
target_link_libraries( main ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
target_link_libraries( main fftw3 )
```

Then execute `cmake CMakeLists.txt` and finally `make`

---

The above build's correctly on the following platform:

**OS:** Ubuntu Linux 21.04

**Kernel:** 5.11.0-34-generic

**cmake Version:** 3.18.4

**g++:** 10.3.0

---

Example main.cpp used:

```
#include <fftw3.h>

#define NUM_POINTS 64


#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define REAL 0
#define IMAG 1

void acquire_from_somewhere(fftw_complex* signal) {
    /* Generate two sine waves of different frequencies and
     * amplitudes.
     */

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_POINTS; ++i) {
        double theta = (double)i / (double)NUM_POINTS * M_PI;

        signal[i][REAL] = 1.0 * cos(10.0 * theta) +
                          0.5 * cos(25.0 * theta);

        signal[i][IMAG] = 1.0 * sin(10.0 * theta) +
                          0.5 * sin(25.0 * theta);
    }
}

void do_something_with(fftw_complex* result) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_POINTS; ++i) {
        double mag = sqrt(result[i][REAL] * result[i][REAL] +
                          result[i][IMAG] * result[i][IMAG]);

        printf("%g\n", mag);
    }
}


int main() {
    fftw_complex signal[NUM_POINTS];
    fftw_complex result[NUM_POINTS];

    fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(NUM_POINTS,
                                      signal,
                                      result,
                                      FFTW_FORWARD,
                                      FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    acquire_from_somewhere(signal);
    fftw_execute(plan);
    do_something_with(result);

    fftw_destroy_plan(plan);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I still get the same error... Although there is a fftw3.h in ./fftw/api, I cannot say 100% that this is the one I want.

Comment: Can you give a bit more of a description on what system you are trying to build on and what is the contents of main.cpp?

Comment: @polaupa the above answer has been edited and tested.

Comment: Usually with autoconf systems, libraries will be installed to `/usr/local`, which commonly isn't included in the standard search paths for GCC when it searches for headers and libraries. So "[m]ake sure that you run make install" might not be enough.

Comment: `make install` installs to `/usr/local/include/`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have also included --prefix for ./configure which will install the library in the provided prefix